# Product of Transcendentals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers

I want to prove or disprove that the product of two transcendental is transcendental: (However, not using an inverse identity such as $\pi$ and $\frac1\pi$)

My attempt:

Proof using Hilbert's number: $2^\sqrt2$

The product of Hilbert's number I contend is transcendental: $(2^\sqrt2)^2$
=$2^\sqrt2 * 2^\sqrt2 = 2^{\sqrt2+\sqrt2}= 2^{irrationalnumber}$

$\sqrt2+\sqrt2$ is irrational because there sum has no parts that cancel out.

Thus, $2^{irrationalnumber}$ by Gelfond-Schneider Thorem, any number of the form $a^b$ is transcendental where $a$ and $b$ are algebraic and $b$ is not a rational number.

I dislike the $2^{irrationalnumber}$ and the fact that I used the same two transcendental is the a more stronger proof that use two distinct and no inverse like the questions asks?

Comment: Are you trying to prove a general statement here or do you only care about $2^{2\sqrt{2}}$? Also, saying that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}$ is irrational because "no parts cancel out" is questionable...it is true that this number is irrational, but I would not like to see that explaination on a homework

Comment: The fact that you have to rule out obvious counterexamples, like $\pi$ and $\frac{1}{\pi}$, suggests that this is not the case. Are you also ruling out examples like $2\pi$ and $\frac{1}{\pi}$? How about $\pi \sqrt{3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{7}}{2\pi}$?

Comment: It is currently unknown whether $e\pi$ is transcendental. Any general result about Q's like it would be huge.

Comment: You can say that if $T$ is the set of transcendentals and $x\in T$ then $ \{ y\in T :  xy\in T\}$ is uncountable because $T$ is uncountable and so is $\{xy: y\in \mathbb R\}$ but $\{ y\in T: xy \not \in T\}=\{x/a :a \not \in T\}$ is only countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement "the product of two transcendentals is transcendental" means "the product of **any** two transcendentals is **always** transcendental".  It is true that $2^{\sqrt{2}} \times 2^\sqrt{2} = 2^{2 \sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental, but this is just an example to show that the product of two  transcendentals **can be** transcendental.

If you don't like $\pi$ and $1/\pi$, take any nonzero algebraic number $c$ and any transcendental number $a$.  Then $b = c/a$ will also be transcendental, but $ab = c$ is not transcendental.

Comment: Thanks! I truly appreciate the extension